# Extract specific files from a .zip file with PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, zip, powershell-cmdlet

I currently have a script that I am using to extract specific .xml files from some folders.  However, I need to do the same thing with zip files in these same folders, and the `Expand-Archive` cmdlet can't do exactly what I need to do.  Would anyone be able to offer any help?  Here is my original script:

```
param (
    [string]$loannumber,
    [string]$mids
)

$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"

$MyDir = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)
$config = [xml][IO.File]::ReadAllText("$MyDir\MessageGatherConfig.xml")

#$loannumber = '1479156692'
#$mids = 'M1,M2,DUREQ'

$selectedmids = $mids.Split(",")

foreach ($mid in $selectedmids) {
    $filestocopy = @()
    Write-Host "Checking for $mid messages..."

    $midfile = ($config.MessageGatherConfig.MessageFilePatterns.FilePattern | Where-Object {$_.messageid -eq $mid})
    $pattern = $midfile.pattern

    $copyfiles = $false

    foreach ($path in $midfile.Path) {

        $searchval = $pattern.Replace("LOANNUMBER", $loannumber)

        Write-Host "Searching $path for $searchval"

        $dircmd = "dir /b $path\$searchval"
        $files = ""

        $files = cmd.exe /c $dircmd

        if ($files -ne $null) {
            $copyfiles = $true
            $files = $files.replace('[', '`[')
            $files = $files.replace(']', '`]')

            $files2 = $files.Split([Environment]::NewLine)

            foreach ($filename in $files2) {
                $filestocopy += "$path\$filename"
            }
        }       

    }

    if ($copyfiles) {
        Write-Host "Copying $mid files to local folder"

        if (Test-Path $MyDir\$loannumber\$mid) {
            Remove-Item $MyDir\$loannumber\$mid -Force -Recurse 
        }

        New-Item $MyDir\$loannumber\$mid -type directory
    }
}
```

Comment: Screenshots are not helpful. Please paste an example of the code you're using and tell how it doesn't work (error messages, etc.).

Comment: I just posted my entire original script.  It's not that it doesn't work. I just need it to work for zip files as well, and I am uncertain of how to do that.

Comment: What does "work for zip files as well" mean?

Comment: My script already works when extracting specific files from folders.  These same folders have zip files that I also need to extract specific files from as well.  I am seeking help with editing my script in order to accomplish that.

Comment: Why does `Expand-Archive` not work for you?

Comment: I have a large number of zip files, each of which contain 200+ xml files, I only need a certain few from each zip file.  Expand-Archive extracts every single file, and I haven't found a way to make the cmdlet apply to specific files. i do not need to extract every single file.

Comment: I would recommend a zip tool that lets you extract only certain files.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a method of extracting the zip to a temp directory and then using the function above to copy the files that you need. This simple function will extract the content to a temp directory and return the path to the extracted content.

```
function extractZipToTemp () {
    Param (
        $ZipFilePath
    )

    # Generate the path to extract the ZIP file content to.
    $extractedContentPath = "$([System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath())$(([guid]::NewGuid()).tostring())"
    # Extract the ZIP file content.
    Expand-Archive -Path $ZipFilePath -DestinationPath $extractedContentPath -Force
    # Return the path to the extracted content.
    return $extractedContentPath
}
```

---

If you want the content to remain local to the directory you are executing the script from, just tweak the above function as follows.

```
function extractZipToTemp () {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [String]$ZipFilePath,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [String]$ExtractPath
    )

    # Generate the path to extract the ZIP file content to.
    $extractedContentPath = "$extractPath\$($ZipFilePath | Split-Path -Leaf)"
    # Extract the ZIP file content.
    Expand-Archive -Path $ZipFilePath -DestinationPath $extractedContentPath -Force
    # Return the path to the extracted content.
    return $extractedContentPath
}
```

---

With either of the aforementioned methods, remember to cleanup after copying the files that you need.

Comment: I will give this a shot. Thank you, sir.

Comment: No problem. Just let me know if you need more assistance.